# Do Hong Kong iPhones have the extra option "Apps using WLAN & Cellular"?

Tags: iphone, wifi

Chinese iPhones have an extra option called "Apps using WLAN & Cellular" in Settings > WLAN

Do the Hong Kong iPhones models have this options?

Is there is any iPhone models other than the China models have this option?

[image]